# How to achieve hierarchical serialization to XML in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, nested

Attempting to learn and use a bit more about class serialization to XML.
I can do basic serialisation.

In the following case I have a nested class structure and would like to get it output *in its implemented hierarchy* to a file in XML standard. The same for deserializing if it there are any caveats.
I had a good search but couldn't understand how to do it.

I know some bits below are not 100% safe but I'm more worried about the serialization functionality. The serializer class extends the Serialize() to any of my classes.

Your help is much appreciated.

```
    public class SysConfigs
    {
    public SysConfigs() { }

    public struct DeadVolumes
    {
        public struct Valve
        {
            public uint V1;    //valve 1 dead volume in uL
            public uint V2;    //valve 2 deal volume 
            public uint V3;
            public uint V4;
            public uint V5p0;
            public uint V5p1;
            public uint V5p2;
            public uint V5p3;
            public uint V5p4;
            public uint V5p5;
            public uint v5p6;
            public uint V5p7;
            public uint V5p8;
            public uint V5p9;
            public uint V5p10;
            public uint V5p11;
            public uint V5p12;
            public uint V5p13;
            public uint V5p14;
            public uint V6;
        }

        public struct Mixer
        {
            public uint M1p1;
            public uint M1p2;
            public uint M1p3;
            public uint M2p1;
            public uint M2p2;
            public uint M2p3;
        }
    }    
}

    public static class Serializer
    {
    public static void Serialize(this Object obj, string filePath)
    {
        // Creates an instance of the XmlSerializer class;
        // specifies the type of object to be deserialized.
        XmlSerializer _xml_serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        XmlWriter _xml_textwriter = XmlWriter.Create(filePath);


        try
        {
            _xml_serializer.Serialize(_xml_textwriter, obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        _xml_textwriter.Close();

        // If the XML document has been altered with unknown 
        // nodes or attributes, handles them with the 
        // UnknownNode and UnknownAttribute events.
        _xml_serializer.UnknownNode += new XmlNodeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownNode);
        _xml_serializer.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownAttribute);
    }

    // this is where I am testing the my serialization implementation from
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SysConfigs stuff = new SysConfigs();
        stuff.Serialize("myfile.xml");
    }
```

The example above produces an XML without contents - that is understood.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SysConfigs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

I would like to understand what is required, given the example above, to achieve the following XML program output:

```
<SysConfigs>
  <DeadVolumes>
    <Valve>
      <V1>123</V1>
      <V2>123</V2>
      <V3>123</V3>
     ..etc..
    </Valve>
    <Mixer>
      <M1p1>1</M1p1>
      <M1p2>1</M1p2>
      <M1p3>1</M1p3>
      ..etc..
    </Mixer>
  </DeadVolumes>
</SysConfigs>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. It is unclear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: @CodeCaster hopefully a bit better.

Comment: If the problem is "the file is empty", then that's because the `SysConfig` struct has no members.

Comment: @CodeCaster *sighs* alright buddy. tks for your 'input'.

Comment: Your "sigh" and quoted "input" aren't really helpful. Do you understand my comment or not?

Comment: I understand you might be fed up of reading confusing questions. I think we are both here to learn and help. You'll find that your answer was more constructive and was hopefully met with the same constructiveness.

Comment: You can't expect the same level of detail in a comment as one can write in an answer. The term "members" is very common in object-oriented programming and could have set you on the right track if you [had researched it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113.aspx). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `SysConfigs` class has no members. So there's nothing to serialize. There's also no need to make the structs nested, or to use structs in the first place. So instead just create a series of classes:

```
public class Valve
{
    public uint V1;
    // ...
    public uint V6;
}

public class Mixer
{
    public uint M1p1;
    // ...
    public uint M1p3;
}
```

Then create the container class containing the proper members:

```
public class DeadVolume
{
    public Valve Valve { get;set; }
    public Mixer Mixer { get;set; }
}
```

Then add a property to the `SysConfigs` class:

```
public class SysConfigs
{
    public DeadVolume DeadVolumes { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can instantiate and populate a `SysConfigs` instance and serialize it:

```
var config = new SysConfigs
{
    DeadVolumes = new DeadVolume
    {
        Valve = new Valve
        {
            V1 = 42,
            // ...
        },
        Mixer = new Mixer
        {
            M1p1 = 43,
            // ..
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This makes sense and I understand your approach to solve the problem.
My approach is influenced by my knowledge in C, more and more structs don't seem to me to have a place in C#.

Anyway, I feel I need to read more about this - having syntactically "public Valve Valve { get;set; }" confuses me and I don't know what that means.
Can you point me the name of this concept so I can read up?

cheers

Comment: Your confusion seems to stem that nested _classes_ result in nested _values_, but they don't. You generally don't use nesting in C#, all classes just live inside a namespace. So in order to create a member that actually holds an instance of a class, you could use a property like I did there: `public Valve Valve { get; set; }` indicates that the `DeadVolume` class has a `Valve` _member_ that you can assign, so it will be serialized. Relevant: [MSDN: Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Comment: "You generally don't use nesting in C#, all classes just live inside a namespace" - this has made a lot of sense! The properties used in that fashion are new ground to me but definitely an elegant solution within C#. I had seen explicit Serializer tags for data members, where here the property _assignment properties_ implicitly do that - I get it. Thank you.